# Перевести дату в нужный формат в excel

Tags: python, excel, datetime

Имеется дата в виде строки

```
q = '1 october 2022'
```

Нужно получить следующий формат даты

```
10.2022
```

Необходимо конвертировать ее в дату в нужном формате так, чтобы тип данных так же оставался `<class 'datetime.datetime'>`

Есть код

```
qq = date_time_obj = datetime.datetime.strptime(q, '%d %B %Y')
print(type(qq))
date = date_time_obj.date().strftime('%m.%Y')
print(date)
print(type(date))
```

И вывод программы

```
<class 'datetime.datetime'>
10.2022
<class 'str'>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Только наследование

```
class datetime(datetime.datetime):
    def __str__(self):
        return self.date().strftime('%m.%Y')
```

тип конечно не в модуле.

```
>>> q = '1 october 2022'
>>> date_time_obj = datetime.strptime(q, '%d %B %Y')
>>> print(date_time_obj)
10.2022
>>> type(date_time_obj)
<class '__main__.datetime'>
```

Comment: Ваш вариант работает, но почему-то при записи данного значения в excel файл, там выводится совершенно другое "01.10.2022  00:00:00"

Comment: @ЕленаСергеева ну вы же сами хотели, чтобы тип данных не менялся. в эксель данные загружаются как оригинальный datetime.datetime. а в этом вопросе вам показали пример _отображения_ в том виде. в котором вы хотели.

Comment: я нашла решение проблемы. там с помощью библиотеки openpyxl можно задать формат ячейки, который подходит под это решение)

Comment: @ЕленаСергеева а вы опубликуйте свое решение как ответ. и вам плюс и людям польза.

Comment: в вопросе бы написали что нужен формат ячейки)

Answer (score 2):

Для того, чтобы добавить дату в нужном формате в excel файл, можно воспользоваться библиотекой `openpyxl`

```
import openpyxl

class datetime(datetime.datetime):
    def __str__(self):
        return self.date().strftime('%m.%Y')

q = '1 october 2022'
date_time_obj = datetime.strptime(q, '%d %B %Y')

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(name_file)
ws = wb.active
rows = ws.max_row

cell = ws.cell(row = rows+1, column = 1)
cell.number_format = 'M.YYYY'
cell.value = date_time_obj
cell.alignment = Alignment(horizontal="right")

wb.save(name_file)
```